# Passing parameters to SetAnimationDidStopSelector in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, core-animation

I'm using some animation and wanting to call a method after the animation completes.  If I set the method like so, all is fine.  But how should I set the selector if I want to pass in a parameter?:

```
UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector (new Selector("EndItAll"));
```

ie:

```
[Export]
public void EndItAll(string myValue)
{
...
```

If it's easier to do it with block animation I'd be happy to use that too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you try to achieve? Can you store parameter as local variable?

Or you can use block animation with closure:

```
var myValue = "someValue";
UIView.Animate (
    duration,
    () => /* your animation code */,
    () => Console.WriteLine (myValue)
);
```

Comment: You are exactly right!  That makes it far easier than the old method.  Thanks Alexey.